# PowerVR SGX540 Android texture issue

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, powervr-sgx

I am trying to load some textures in my android application.

It works well on all the devices like samsung galaxy ace, s2 
but any device using PowerVR SGX540 gpu, e.g. samsung galaxy S-gti9000
will have some weird artifacts....

Some textures are loaded correctly... 
but other textures are completely black....

I have made sure that all my textures are power-of-two,
but they are not square and can be rectangular e.g.  64*128.

I am using the following for texture paramaters settings....

```
gl.glActiveTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE0);               
gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, glTextureId);
gl.glTexParameterf(gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, gl.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.GL_LINEAR);
gl.glTexParameterf(gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, gl.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.GL_LINEAR); 
gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
```

Comment: Are you using bitmapFactory to decode your resources? Sometimes it shrinks/enlarges images based on the screen density.

Comment: Hi Tim, not BitmapFactory... but using ETC textures with ETC1Util.createTexture()... i checked the dimensions of all my textures now and they are all power of two as expected...

Comment: it is surprising that some textures are loaded perfectly but others are not

Answer (score 1):

As Tim suggests, it could be android helpfully resizing your images to match the dpi of different devices.

Check the size of the images once their loaded to ensure that they're still power-of-two.
Putting the resource files in `res/drawable-nodpi` should let android know that you don't want them resized.

Comment: hi, there is only one bitmap that i am using like            Bitmap.createBitmap(256, 256, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);

The rest of them are loaded as the ETC texture directly from inputsrteam using ETC1Util.createTexture(inputsrteam );

Comment: I checked also that some of my mip maps have  dimension less than 2 like 1*1